# Why can't I chain String.prototype.toLowerCase with underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, prototype, underscore.js, chaining

I think the issue is not with underscore.js, but rather with Native prototypes functions. It seems that one can only call them directly, not passing them as callbacks. Here's the code the I can't use and the error from my tests (using Mocha.js, only the relevant portion):

```
_.chain("INPUT").tap(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
// => TypeError: String.prototype.toLowerCase called on null or undefined
```

So tried this in Node's REPL :

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase("INPUT")
// => ''
```

I know one should call a prototype's function with `.call` or `.apply`, but why exactly ? And how can I pass this function as a callback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype methods are using `this` internally to refer to the object that should get manipulated.

`call` and `apply` lets you specify the `this` value when calling a function.

```
String.prototype.toLowerCase.call('INPUT'); //input
```

If you want to bind a `this` value to a function so that it's invocation form doesn't matter, you can do it with `_.bind` or `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
var lowerCaseInput = String.prototype.toLowerCase.bind('INPUT');

lowerCaseInput(); //input
```

Now, calling `_.chain` on an object will wrap it in an underscore object and returns the wrapper and `_.tap` takes the result of the previous function in the chain as it's input. Right here we see it's not going to work since `String.prototype.toLowerCase` doesn't even expect arguments.

Not only this, but strings are immutable so you would have to do something like the following:

```
_.chain({ text: 'INPUT' }).tap(function (obj) {
    obj.text = obj.text.toLowerCase();
}).value().text;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `this`... I start to like it less and less. I ended up creating a simple wrapper function like `function lowerCase(input) { return input.toLowerCase(); }`. Simpler in my mind, less prototype and objects. Too bad we can't pass prototype's functions like other regular functions...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you use mixins,  you can use a `mixin` that simply wraps `toLowerCase`.

```
_.mixin({
    toLowerCase: function(str) {
        // Add here any desired validation if wanted
        return str.toLowerCase();
    }
}, {
    chain: false
});
```

After, you can do something like:

```
_.chain('HELLO_WORLD')
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace('_',' ')
    .value()
```